# How can I reverse this animation smoothly on mouseout?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this flipcard I put together, and when you hover over it, it flips 180 degrees on it's x-axis, and then expands. When I mouse-off of the element, I would like for this element to flip back the opposite way smoothly, the way it came in. Instead of the sudden change back when you mouseout like it is right now.

Also, it should be noted that I would like the animation to use `animation: forwards` for as long as the mouse is hovering over the element. (ie. so long as the user is hovering over the element, it should remain flipped, and enlarged.)

Is there any way to do this using just CSS? Or will I need Javascript? If so, I'd like to do this with pure Vanilla JS.

I have been poking around for solutions on Stack Overflow, and can't seem to find a definitive answer, or am not typing in the correct question.

```css
html, body {
  background: #f2edea;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 250px;
  height: 320px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 35%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.flipcard {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  top: 20%;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px #94989e;
  border: 3px solid #b8b8ba;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: pink;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
} 

@keyframes grow {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(0) scale(1);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(2);
  }
}

.flipcard:hover {
  animation: grow 1s forwards;
}

.front-side  {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  
}

.back-side {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='flipcard'>
  <div class='front-side'>
    <img src='https://pre00.deviantart.net/4121/th/pre/i/2018/059/6/7/brigitte_by_raikoart-dc4kzas.png'>
  </div>
  <div class='back-side'>
    <img src="https://img00.deviantart.net/e0ec/i/2017/297/8/c/mercy_by_raikoart-dbrm54b.png">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: if the animation was like that in your previous question i would have recommended transition as the first option :) why ? because the animation here is a silmple "from to" which you can easily transform to a transition but if you consider your initial complex animation with many states it won't be easy ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd better use `transition` between normal and hover states.
Note that you have to track `hover` on `.container` to avoid jumping and flickering.

```css
html, body {
  background: #f2edea;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 250px;
  height: 320px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.flipcard {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  top: 20%;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px #94989e;
  border: 3px solid #b8b8ba;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: pink;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
} 

.container:hover .flipcard {
    transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(2);
}

.front-side  {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  
}

.back-side {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='flipcard'>
  <div class='front-side'>
    <img src='https://pre00.deviantart.net/4121/th/pre/i/2018/059/6/7/brigitte_by_raikoart-dc4kzas.png'>
  </div>
  <div class='back-side'>
    <img src="https://img00.deviantart.net/e0ec/i/2017/297/8/c/mercy_by_raikoart-dbrm54b.png">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was definitely overthinking this process. This is a much more simple and straightforward solution. I assume that the reason you would want to put the `:hover` on the `.container` is because if the it was on `.flipcard`, then when the y-axis became 0 during the transition, I would be hovering over the `.container`, which doesn't have a transform transition, so it would cause the flickering?

Comment: @WonkasWilly, exactly, if `:hover` set to`.flipcard` directly, when `.flipcard` gets `:hover` it rotates and goes off of the mouse cursor. It causes `:hover` off and `.flipcard` turns back until it meets the cursor again. Then `:hover` triggers again and everything repeats causing flickering.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for the confirmation. :)

Comment: @WonkasWilly, happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

The reason this happens is because on the default non-hover state there's no animation state to return to. You have two options for this.

1. Don't use animations and just transition the effect on hover.

This way on out the properties will return to their non-hover state with transition.

```
.flipcard {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  top: 20%;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px #94989e;
  border: 3px solid #b8b8ba;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: pink;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateY(0) scale(1);
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
} 

.flipcard:hover {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(2);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/255mnwxr/5/

2. To have a out animation property.

This is least desired because on load the animation will play once for it to animate then it acts naturally afterwards.

```
.flipcard {
  animation: return 1s forwards;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  top: 20%;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px #94989e;
  border: 3px solid #b8b8ba;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: pink;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
} 

@keyframes grow {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(0) scale(1);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(2);
  }
}

@keyframes return {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(2);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateY(0) scale(1);
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/255mnwxr/2/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add @keyframes on the mouse in and out hover.

```css
html, body {
  background: #f2edea;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 250px;
  height: 320px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 35%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.flipcard {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  top: 20%;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px #94989e;
  border: 3px solid #b8b8ba;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: pink;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
} 


@-webkit-keyframes in {
    from   { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to {-webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(2);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes out {
    0%   { -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(2); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
}

.flipcard:hover {
  animation: out 1s forwards;
}

.flipcard {
  animation: in 1s forwards;
}

.front-side  {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  
}

.back-side {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='flipcard'>
  <div class='front-side'>
    <img src='https://pre00.deviantart.net/4121/th/pre/i/2018/059/6/7/brigitte_by_raikoart-dc4kzas.png'>
  </div>
  <div class='back-side'>
    <img src="https://img00.deviantart.net/e0ec/i/2017/297/8/c/mercy_by_raikoart-dbrm54b.png">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a keyframe animation for this, you could just use basic CSS transitions for this, they'll rewind on mouseout with the `transition` property:

```
.flipcard {
  transform: rotateY(0) scale(1);
  transition: 1s all ease-out;
} 

.flipcard:hover {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(2);
}
```

However, if you do want to use animations (for more complex interactions) I have a snippet for that at the bottom, just know this can be a little harder to maintain, and just reversing it on the default element won't work.

Also note that you may want a mouse-container that doesn't rotate but controls the hover state otherwise the mouse may fall off part way through the transition, like:

```
.flipcard-container:hover .flipcard {
    transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(2);
}
```

```css
html, body {
  background: #f2edea;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 250px;
  height: 320px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 35%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.flipcard {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  top: 20%;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px #94989e;
  border: 3px solid #b8b8ba;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: pink;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateY(0) scale(1);
  transition: 1s all ease-out;
} 

.flipcard:hover {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(2);
}

.front-side  {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  backface-visibility: hidden;

}

.back-side {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='flipcard'>
    <div class='front-side'>
      <img src='https://pre00.deviantart.net/4121/th/pre/i/2018/059/6/7/brigitte_by_raikoart-dc4kzas.png'>
    </div>
    <div class='back-side'>
      <img src="https://img00.deviantart.net/e0ec/i/2017/297/8/c/mercy_by_raikoart-dbrm54b.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
html, body {
  background: #f2edea;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 250px;
  height: 320px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 35%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

@keyframes grow {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(0) scale(1);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(2);
  }
}

@keyframes shrink {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(2);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateY(0) scale(1);
  }
}

.flipcard {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  top: 20%;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px #94989e;
  border: 3px solid #b8b8ba;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: pink;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateY(0) scale(1);
  animation: shrink 1s forwards;
} 


.flipcard:hover {
  animation: grow 1s forwards;
}

.front-side  {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  
}

.back-side {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='flipcard'>
    <div class='front-side'>
      <img src='https://pre00.deviantart.net/4121/th/pre/i/2018/059/6/7/brigitte_by_raikoart-dc4kzas.png'>
    </div>
    <div class='back-side'>
      <img src="https://img00.deviantart.net/e0ec/i/2017/297/8/c/mercy_by_raikoart-dbrm54b.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```